# How to make weak reference when setting function to closure variable

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

How to weak self when setting function to closure as in **1.** to work same as example **2.** Any ideas?

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {
 func setupViewActions() {
  tabView.itemTapped = changeTab // 1. tabController cannot be deallocated

  tabView.itemTapped = { [weak self] tab in // 2. TabController can be deallocated
  changeTab(tab: tab)
  }
 }

 func changeTab(tab: TabItem) {
  self.selectedIndex = tab.index
 }
}
enum TabItem {
 var index: int
}

class TabView: UIView {
 var itemTapped: ((_ tab: TabItem) -> Void)?
}
```

Comment: Make `itemTapped` a `weak` property.

Comment: @Paulw11 then I am getting error: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '(FxTabItem) -> Void'

Comment: Either adopt a delegate pattern, use the closure as you have or explicitly clear the function when required

Comment: or change func changeTab to return closure (where I can make self weak) and then set it to variable. Seems like setting func to closure just because it has same parameter is a risky idea. Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see any problem with

```swift
tabView.itemTapped = { [weak self] tab in
    changeTab(tab: tab)
}
```

In my opinion, this is pretty common pattern in Swift and, especially, Cocoa.

**However**, if you really want to get rid of this curly braces, you can use this wrapper function using [parameter packs](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0393-parameter-packs.md):

```swift
func weakifySelf<T: AnyObject, each R>(
    _ self: T,
    _ target: @escaping (T) -> (repeat each R) -> Void
) -> ((repeat each R) -> Void) {
    { [weak self](input: repeat each R) in
        guard let self else { return }
        
        target(self)(repeat each input)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```swift
class Top {
    let bottom = Bottom()
    
    func setup() {
        self.bottom.handler = weakifySelf(self, Top.doJob)
    }
    
    func doJob(int: Int, string: String) {
        print("\(int) \(string)")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Top deallocated")
    }
}

class Bottom {
    var handler: ((Int, String) -> Void)?
    
    func foo() {
        self.handler?(42, "Hello")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Bottom deallocated")
    }
}

func test() {
    let top = Top()
    top.setup()
    top.bottom.foo()
}

test()
```

Code above prints

```
42 Hello
Top deallocated
Bottom deallocated
```